# Array of different types object - class-transformer

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm trying to validate an array of objects that could have different types of objects.
For example:

```js
const objA = { ... } // Some properties
const objB = { ... } // Different properties from objA
```

The array can contain either:

```js
const mixedArray = Array<objA | objB>;
```

I'm trying to validate this array coming in a property in an API

```js
class ExampleDTO {
   @IsArray()
   @ArrayNotEmpty()
   @ValidateNested({ each: true })
   @Type(() => ????)
   readonly mixedArray: Array<objA | objB>;
}
```

How do I define the `@Type` to include multiple custom types to be validated?

Any ideas? On how to do it differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ObjA and ObjB are two **classes**, You have to use conditional `@Transform` instead of `@Type`, however you need at least a factor to differentiate between ObjA and ObjB.

For example objA have a property named `iAmObjA` but objB does not, so you can change type decorator like this:

```js
class ExampleDTO {
   @IsArray()
   @ArrayNotEmpty()
   @ValidateNested({ each: true })
   @Transform(({ value }) => value?.map(o => plainToClass(o.iAmObjA ? ObjA : ObjB, o)))
   readonly mixedArray: Array<objA | objB>;
}
```

Comment: I see, I was struggling with this for a while, this seems like a possible solution. Thanks!